# How to select data and put it on label text coming from HTTP request in Xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin, request

I am very beginner in Xamarin ,I am trying to create app and need some help ,I have a PHP page in server which get Json data for one user ,just one row :-

```
<?php
include_once 'DbConnect.php';
$username = $_GET['username'];
    $username=strip_tags($username);
    $username=trim($username);
    $username=stripslashes($username);
    $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$username);
 
        $user = "SELECT * FROM users Where username = '$username'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$user);
                $user_status= array();

                foreach ($result as $row){
                    array_push ($user_status,array(
                's_id'=> $row['s_id'],
                'm_id'=> $row['m_id'],
                'd_id'=> $row['d_id'],
                
            ));
                }
            echo utf8_encode (json_encode($user_status));
?>
```

On a page on Xamarin i request this page to get data above :

```
private async void GetStatus()
        {
            HttpClient MyStatus = new HttpClient();
            var responsestatus = await MyStatus.GetStringAsync("xxx/api/userstatus.php?username="+ myparam.Text);
            var myStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.UserStatus>>(responsestatus);

            var Result = from MyItem in myStatus
                         select MyItem;

        }
```

So I have this Class Model:

```
class UserStatus
    {
        public string s_id { get; set; }
        public string m_id { get; set; }
        public string d_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I receive one row of ( s_id ,m_id and d_id  ) ,I want to put each one of them on label text to show them , How Can I do that?
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a XAML page with three `Labels` and give them names

```
<ContentPage ... >
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
     <Label x:Name="Label1" />
     <Label x:Name="Label2" />
     <Label x:Name="Label2" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

then in your xaml.cs page, after you receive your data

```
HttpClient MyStatus = new HttpClient();
var responsestatus = await MyStatus.GetStringAsync("xxx/api/userstatus.php?username="+ myparam.Text);
var myStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.UserStatus>>(responsestatus);

Label1.Text = myStatus[0].s_id;
Label1.Text = myStatus[0].m_id;
Label1.Text = myStatus[0].d_id;
```

Comment: Thanx alot it works correctly ,I tride with MyItem[0].s_id and Result [0].s_id but i didn't thought of  myStatus[0].s_id; thank you again

Comment: can i convert coming data to int?

Comment: yes, define the files as int in your UserStatus class

Comment: @sermed Hi , if answer be helpful and solved that  , remember to mark it when you have time :-)